# How to store "return url" value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

We have a separate views for listing A) people B) organizations, C) others but when the user wants to EDIT any one of those, e.g. a person, he would get redirected to a common view, with its own controller.

After the user clicks "Save person", he is to be redirected back to the view that he came from. So some sort of ReturnUrl.

In other words, depending on where the user came from, that is where he must land again after "Save".

Our approach was to make the ReturnUrl part of the ViewModel:

```
class PersonEditModel : ViewModelBase
{
   ...
   public string ReturnUrl {get;set;}
}
```

If this is set, a Redirect happens.

What is the best way to accomplish this in MVC 5?

Comment: There is no "best way", but there are "some ways". Whether a way of doing this is acceptable depends on your requirements. Show what you have tried. If you search "asp.net mvc return url" you'll find plenty of hits.

Comment: That doesn't change what I addressed with my previous comment, it still asks for "the best way" which is opinion-based. It works, so what is your question? Of course you don't want to add a ReturnUrl to each ViewModel, but is that your question? _"What is an alternative to storing the ReturnUrl in the model, so I don't have to alter all my viewmodels"_? I'm not being pedantic, I want your question to be clear.

Comment: You could just pass the returnUrl in as a parameter when you make a call to the action method?